# Can't restore Time Machine backup in Catalina

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, catalina, airport

My old my MacBook was stolen so I have to buy a new one. I have an Airport Time Capsule, so I have the Time Machine backups. Yesterday I plugged the new MacBook for the first time and tried to recover the information and everything went smooth until it got stuck for a few hours, so I decided to reboot and give it another try. This time, using Migration Assistant, because I did not have time to go through the whole backup. When I used the Migraton Assistant, I got an error like the following:

> Some backups cannot be opened.
>
> Make sure that all of your network devices are
> connected and turned on. It appears that some
> backups are already in use. If you don't see the
> backup you need, make sure it is not currently
> mounted by another machine and try again.

So I started googling and the first thing that I've realized is that the extension of the backup files on the newer OS's is `.backupbundle` instead of `.sparsebundle`. Anyways, I proceeded with the steps that suggest to mount the bundle in order to repair it using `fsck`. It doesn't work for me because every time that I try to mount the image, I get something like this:

```
cristobal@cristobals-mbp Data % hdiutil attach -nomount -readwrite /Volumes/Data/Cristóbal’s\ MacBook\ Pro.backupbundle 
/dev/disk2
```

As I understand, I should see something like this:

```
/dev/disk2              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk2s2            Apple_HFSX
```

I also tried the following:

- Change extension to `.sparsebundle`
- Change the state `VerificationState` in `com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist` from `1` to `0`
- Tried to recover with disk drill but doesn't work on Airport Time Capsule

I'm very desperate to recover the files, so every help will be welcome.